# Deterministically encode a dictionary as a url parameter list in Python

Tags: python, url, dictionary

I'm using [urllib.parse.urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) to generate the parameters string of a url. The input to the function is a dictionary. The problem with calling `urlencode` on a dictionary is that the output is not deterministic. Namely, the order of the parameters in the resulting string is not consistent. The undeterministic behavior of `urlencode` makes it hard to test pieces of code that use it. Is there a deterministic equivalent of `urlencode`?

My current solution is to transform the dictionary into a list of tuples, sort it and then iterate the sorted list and generate the string. I'm asking whether such a function already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) accepts not only mapping (dictionary), but also a sequence of two-element tuple:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode([('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')])
'a=b&c=d'
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode([('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b')])
'c=d&a=b'
```

If instead you just need an ordered mapping, use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I wasn't clear about the fact that I have to use dictionaries. So the solution you suggest is equivalent to the one I've proposed in the question (transforming the dictionary into a sorted list of tuples and only then encoding the list).

Comment: @snakile, Dictionary is an unordered collection. If you need an ordered mapping use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use dicts then you can convert them to an `OrderedDict` before passing them to `urlencode`:

```python
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
urlencode(OrderedDict(sorted(d.items())))
```

This will convert the dict to the ordered two-element tuple falsetru mentions.